# How to avoid implicit conversion from char to int when using arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have templated some code which I want to specialize for both `int` and `char`. In this code, I use the arithmetic operator `operator+`. When I compile using `g++` (conversion warnings, warnings treated as errors) the compiler complains that my `char`s are implicitly converted to `int`s and every further assignment triggers a narrowing conversion warning.

Here is some basic code to reproduce this issue:

```
template<typename T>
T add(const T a, const T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    const char a = 1;
    const char b = 2;

    const char c = add<char>(a, b); // a and b implicitely converted to int.
                                    // Assignement to c fails (narrowing)

    (void)c;

    return 0;
}
```

which you can compile (it should fail) using:

```
g++ -Wconversion -Werror main.cpp
```

I know that this is because the smallest built-in type for which `operator+` is defined is `int`, so when you use smaller types, they silently get converted to fit the arguments.

I am looking for a way to avoid this and minimize casting. I know for example that I could cast the result the addition of `a` and `b` to `char`, but for additions with many terms, it soon becomes a mess to read.

How could I do this?

---

The error I get:

```
main.cpp:4:16: error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
     return a + b;
                ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: There's no way to avoid the promotion.

Comment: Note that the promotion does not occur on the line with the comment. The promotion occurs inside the template function. The narrowing conversion occurs in the `return` statement in `add`. The assignment to `c` is not a problem: `add<char>` returns `char`. There is no promotion there, and no narrowing conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yeah, formally [this is the case](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion):

> ... arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as
>   arguments, and ***integral promotions*** are automatically applied after
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion [...]

But why would you want to change or avoid this behavior? If you do something like you suggested, and maybe cast the return value like this:

```
template<typename T>
T add(const T a, const T b)
{
    return static_cast<T>(a + b);
}
```

than you're getting pretty quickly to the risk of [*integer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) in the returned `char` due to its small size to begin with. Is there any reason for you to avoid the promotion in your scenario?

Comment: Or just write the template function with the cast: `return static_cast<T>(a + b);`. No need for specialization. Even better: turn off stupid warnings.

Comment: @PeteBecker Your's is a better example indeed for what I wanted to say, no apparent need to involve the specialization. I've edited the answer. Thank you sir

Comment: I was unit testing a templated vector class (a math vector, not a container) and I added test cases for shorter types (`char` and `short`) and that's where the warning came up. Your answer makes me realize though that this, as well as being overzealous, is dangerous.